# iOS native smartbanner developer documentation

Tags: ios, smartbanner

Do somebody of you know, where to get complete information about options/properties of native iOS safari smartbanner?

For example - For how long smartbanner is hidden when user presses close, or "View" application in iTunes?

I've just closed my during testing and now can't get it back, so i don't know if it still works or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could go with a custom implementation using external libraries like [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js) instead. It's quite flexible and the footprint is relatively small at ~14KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only documentation available on this is over at the Apple Developer site, [Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: That's the only conditionally "normal" documentation I've also found earlier. But I hoped, that there is some more information on this one. And if that's the only thing, than that's bad :) Thanks for answer anyway.